# Problem with crypt function in Perl to SHA-512 password

Tags: perl, sha512

I just started learning Perl and I have a task to compare user input variable with SHA-512 stored hashed password. I made below function to test. I use randomly generated salt to generate digest from real password (p2). Next, I use this digest as salt for my user entered password (p1) to be compared with digest value. This is based on description I have found [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt.html).
I use crypt function to generate digest, however I am not able to display or compare it in next if step.
The password should be hashed using SHA-512.
I appreciate your help.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub HashThis {
    # p1 is userinput and p2 is real password
    my ($p1, $p2) = @_;

    my $salt = join '', ('.', '/', 0..9, 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z')[rand 64, rand 64];

    # makes digest for real password using our pre defined salt
    my $digest = crypt($p2, '$6$'.$salt);

    # compares if crypt return same digest as using digest as salt for userinput
    if (crypt($p1, $digest) eq $digest) {
        print "*** matching ***\n";
    } else {
        die "*** not matching ***\n";
    }
}

print "Enter a word:\t\t ";
chomp(my $userinput = <STDIN>);

print "Real password:\t\t ";
chomp(my $userpass = <STDIN>);

HashThis($userinput, $userpass);
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out what the two calls of `crypt` return to see if and how they differ?

Comment: That's where I have the problem. When I want to print $digest it gives me "Use of uninitialized value $digest ... <STDIN>." error.

Comment: Needs a [mcve] too, not just one function.

Comment: Just updated the code. Please have another look.

Comment: You want the user to manually enter first the hashed password and then a plaintext one? And have you verified that `crypt` is actually working on your system? An undefined value suggests it might not be.

Comment: p1: this is just a test for the function. Ideally, user's entered password will be compared with DB stored password.
p2: that's good question. How can I verify if crypt works on my system? can I only use crypt on linux machine?

Comment: Note that SHA-512 is not an appropriate password hashing algorithm, it's too fast. See [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I appreciate if you answer my p2 question.

Comment: running the code on CentOS I was able to get desired results. Thanks Shawn.

Comment: You just pointed to the right problem. The crypt function was not functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crypt` is a thin wrapper around the [C `crypt` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)). Its [implementation will vary from environment to environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Support_in_operating_systems). Here on OS X it does not take a leading $x$ to indicate which algorithm to use, it just uses DES. `crypt("foo", '$6$'.$salt);` results in `$6A86JNndVTdM`. Only the first two bytes of the salt are used, `$6`.

If you want to use SHA-512, use [Digest::SHA](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA).

`crypt` and [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) are inappropriate for password hashing. Its short key makes it very easy to defeat, and its salt is just two characters. SHA-512 is also not appropriate for password hashing, it's too fast. Instead, you want a dedicated password hashing function such as [`bcrypt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and other [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) algorithms. Some implementations of `crypt` can do bcrypt, many can not.

[`rand` is also not cryptographically secure](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#rand-EXPR) and is inappropriate for generating salts. Instead, use Crypt::Random, Data::Entropy, Math::Random::Secure, or Math::TrulyRandom.

I would recommend using [Crypt::PBKDF2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::PBKDF2), following the instructions in [Storing Password in an easy and secure way using Perl](https://perlmaven.com/storing-passwords-in-a-an-easy-but-secure-way), and reading [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) for the theory.